# Animation bug with always displayed large titles after popping view controller

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios11, uinavigationitem, large-title

I wanted to use the new **Large Titles** with `largeTitleDisplayMode` set to `.always` but got some strange animation issues while popping the pushed detail controller if the root `UITableView`'s `contentOffset.y` is positive aka scrolled.

So this is how it should work:

[image]

And this is how it works after scrolling:

[image]

I guess it's a bug, but maybe anyone have a workaround till it's fixed?

To reproduce, create a new sample project, open Storyboard and do the following:

1. Add `Navigation Controller` and tick it's `Navigation Bar`'s `Prefers Large Titles` value
2. Select it's `Root View Controller` and set it's `Table View`'s `Content` to `Static Cells`.
3. Add many static cells or make then big enough, so your `Table View` become scrollable
4. Add a `View Controller` as detail view controller and setup the `Show` segues
5. Setup the `Navigation Item`'s `Large Titles` property to `Always` for both view controller
6. Run the app, scroll to the bottom, perform a show/push segue and pop back

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code in the 'root' view controller's `viewDidAppear`? And with your current settings does the large title collapse when the 'root' table view is scrolled?

Comment: not a single line, but edit my question to give some fast details to reproduce my issue.

Comment: I have the exact same issue... Any solutions yet?